# Installation of Yosemite taking over 20h

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, install

Yesterday I started installing Yosemite on my MacBookPro 2011.
It all went well until it started rebooting. It is stuck on the Apple grey screen for over 20h now. The progress bar is at the very same point (half way) since 20 hours ago. What to do?

Comment: did you loose your Internet connection ?

Comment: No, as far as I know internet kept working correctly (I was using it on the other computer and did not notice any failure).

Comment: Normally not recommended, since something might happen, if you hold the power button for 10 sec to Force the shut down. Now you can try to start over, hoping nothing serious was broken (like the disk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not recommending this to anyone, just thought I'd report on what worked for me:

- Let Yosemite upgrade sit at the white progress bar screen at 50% for 4 hours.
- Once I was nearly positive it wasn't doing anything like writing to the hard drive...
- Held power button for 10 seconds to turn computer off
- Waited about 10 seconds again
- Turned power on and held Command R  (It took about 3 minutes to boot)
- Clicked on WI-Fi symbol on upper right and turned off Wi-Fi
- Selected restart from the System menu option
- Computer rebooted and finished the upgrade

I have since rebooted (twice to be sure) and run a few things and all seems fine at this point.